# Copying css and html code from others, Copyright infringement?

Tags: html, css

This might not be a coding question, but very relevant to coding so I hoped I would get an answer here. All coders, maybe specially designer. Use others code in there own code. If you see something you like. you use that code in your design. In some degree, I'm sure every coder does this. So I was wondering where the line goes.

Can you use others complete css file and have a almost identical design as another site? With completely different content off course. Or is this Copyright infringement? And how can you confirm that people have Copyright on something?

Where can you find information on the laws on this? Thanks

Comment: All answers to this question should probably be prefixed with "IANAL".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All code, like all content, unless explicitly released under a more permissive license, is copyrighted. Copying snippets of neat features on other sites, which is, of course, done *a lot*, will probably fall under "Fair Use" (look it up) in the US, or similar regulations elsewhere. However, copying a complete style sheet or HTML template, without prior permission from the author, **is  illegal**. There's a lot of free and gratis HTML+CSS templates out there, you can always start from those to create your own design and code. Do, however, read the terms and conditions carefully; "forgetting" an acknowledgement probably isn't allowed either, and makes you look double the fool.

Comment: @ms2ger this is a good answer to a very gray question.

Comment: One other issue, kind of a sidebar to this main issue, if you're going to use the code, even legally, unless its in something like a Google CDN, host a copy on your server, don't just link to it on the site you found it. ;) I have heard of someone getting threatened with a lawsuit for removing a picture from his website, because someone else had linked to it on his ecommerce site, and felt entitled to its use. Suit was dropped...eventually.

Comment: So taking let say 40 lines from a 250 line css file is on the "fair use" side?

Comment: I'd think that's a bit on the wrong side already, but it all depends on the circumstances. If you aren't sure, drop the author an email.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think the code itself, or a part of it, will be seen as a copyright infringement, by a judge. As long as your site doesn't look to much the same, in design, it should not be a problem.

Comment: The code is what defines the end user experience, copying this is legally and morally incorrect.  How would you feel if you spent a year developing a piece of software, only to find someone stole it, rebranded it and sold it as their own?